# SQL error while creating table

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, create-table

I am running following query throgh phpMyAdmin:

```
**CREATE TABLE folders (
  folder_id SERIAL NOT NULL,
  parent_id BIGINT,
  folder_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (folder_id),
FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES folders(folder_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB;**
```

but it is giving the following error:
 **#1005 - Can't create table 'filesharingnew.folders' (errno: 150)**
Any idea where I am wrong?

Comment: you are adding a foreign key constraint on same table ???

Comment: Have you googled error 150??? It could be a privileges thing.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063141/mysql-foreign-key-error-1005-errno-150.

Comment: It runs perfectly if I remove ENGINE=InnoDB. But I have to add support for cascade deletion of records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MySQL docs, [Numeric Type Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html):

> `SERIAL` is an alias for `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE`.

You should change `parent_id` into `BIGINT UNSIGNED` so it matches the referenced column.