# MySQL 1005 error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1005

I am writing a database in MySQL for my online portfolio website to catalog all my designs/pieces of work I have done for clients / projects and I am doing this in order to make adding new works easier instead of having to edit the mark up manually.

Anyway, I tried running the script below:

```
create table album (
   AlbumID int not null,
   AlbumOrder int not null,
   AlbumName varchar(100),
   primary key (AlbumID, AlbumOrder)
);

create table category (
   CategoryID int not null primary key auto_increment,
   CategoryName varchar(100)
);

create table item (
   ItemID int not null primary key auto_increment,
   CategoryID int not null,
   AlbumID int not null,
   AlbumOrder int not null,
   ItemName varchar(100),
   Description varchar(500),
   ThumbPath varchar(100),
   PhotoPath varchar(100),
   InsertDate datetime,
   EditDate datetime,
   constraint fk_catID foreign key (CategoryID) references category (CategoryID) on update cascade,
   constraint fk_albID foreign key (AlbumID) references album (AlbumID) on update cascade,
   constraint fk_albOrd foreign key (AlbumOrder) references album (AlbumOrder) on update cascade
);
```

I get the 1005 error saying the item table can't be created. I have no idea where the problem lies but I am sure it's really obvious!

EDIT: the engine used is innoDB.

Comment: First of all - you need to ensure you dont have the table with same name already in DB. Next u need to create album and category tables before creating item table.

Comment: i have tried that and it still gives the error.

Comment: `AlbumID` is not a PK and thus has no index (also `AlbumOrder`). This might lead to the issue as described in the accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063141/mysql-foreign-key-error-1005-errno-150

Comment: ok, will give that a shot.

Comment: Just gave your solution a try Markus and it worked nicely, i had a look in the relational view for the item table and all the foreign keys were generated...Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your fks to Album may be causing the issue. You should have a single FK based on the 2 columns rather than 2 FKs based on 1 column each, like so (removing the fk_albOrd line):

```
constraint fk_albID foreign key (AlbumID,AlbumOrder) references album (AlbumID,AlbumOrder) on update cascade
```

This script creates the tables without error in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/):

```
create table album (
   AlbumID int not null,
   AlbumOrder int not null,
   AlbumName varchar(100),
   primary key (AlbumID, AlbumOrder)
);

create table category (
   CategoryID int not null primary key auto_increment,
   CategoryName varchar(100)
);

create table item (
   ItemID int not null primary key auto_increment,
   CategoryID int not null,
   AlbumID int not null,
   AlbumOrder int not null,
   ItemName varchar(100),
   Description varchar(500),
   ThumbPath varchar(100),
   PhotoPath varchar(100),
   InsertDate datetime,
   EditDate datetime,
   constraint fk_catID foreign key (CategoryID) references category (CategoryID) on update cascade,
   constraint fk_albID foreign key (AlbumID,AlbumOrder) references album (AlbumID,AlbumOrder) on update cascade

);
```

Comment: yeah, thought it might be obvious :p

Comment: I don't see any problem with having multiple FKs. There is a very big difference between a multi-column FK and two separate FKs - they behave differently and you have to use them differently. If the OP wants three FKs, there's nothing I know of in MySQL that says he can't do it. As I stated in my answer, his code as originally posted runs without errors on my MySQL server.

Comment: i had a look at the relational view in phpmyadmin and this solution did not generate the required relationships.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your statements as they exist right now.

I just executed them successfully on my test mysql environment. However, my environment might be different from yours: my default engine is InnoDB, yours might be something else.

Since you are using Foreign Key Constraints, you should specify explicitly that the engine is InnoDB ("...) engine = Innodb").

It might also be because you already have one or more tables existing. Precede each create with a DROP... IF EXISTS and it should work fine.

Comment: the default engine for me is also innodb but i will also try your solution.

Comment: I never depend on defaults - if the default changes, things break. It is best to always specify what you want.

Answer (score 0):

By running the MySQL statement `show engine innodb status` immediately after receiving the error, you can retrieve further details on the error (output shortened):

```
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR

Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
```

In the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced column is listed as the first column. This is not valid for `fk_albOrd foreign key (AlbumOrder)`.

To solve the issue, you can either add an index to the column `AlbumOrder` on the `Album` table or – preferably – get rid of `fk_albOrd` and change the `fk_albID` constraint to a group of columns as suggested by Derek Kromm:

```sql
constraint fk_albID foreign key (AlbumID, AlbumOrder) references album (AlbumID, AlbumOrder) on update cascade
```