# MySql: ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table '.\mydb\clientaddressdetails.frm' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have used the following syntax. Please help me out in this issue to create foreign key.

```
mysql> create table userdetails(UserId int(3) not null, ClientId int(3) not null, UserName varchar(30), Password varchar(30) character set binary, RoleId int(3) not null, primary key(UserId, ClientId), foreign key(RoleId) references UserRoles(RoleId) on delete cascade on update cascade)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.44 sec)

mysql> create table useraddress (UserId int(3) NOT NULL, Address1 varchar(100),Address2 varchar(100), City varchar(50), Pincode varchar(10), PhoneNumber varchar(20), MobileNumber varchar(20), foreign key(UserId) references userdetails(UserId)on delete cascade on update cascade) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> create table clientaddressdetails (Address1 varchar(100), Address2 varchar(100), City varchar(50), Pincode varchar(10), PhoneNumber varchar(20), MobileNumber varchar(20), ClientId int(3), foreign key(ClientId) references userdetails(ClientId)on delete cascade on update cascade) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table '.\mydb\clientaddressdetails.frm' (errno: 150)
```

Comment: Might need to create an index. See this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063141/mysql-foreign-key-error-1005-errno-150

Comment: Indeed, a `ALTER TABLE userdetails ADD INDEX(ClientId);` & it works, foreign keys need to have an index in the referenced table (may be compound, but then it needs to be the _first_ field in the index).

Comment: Thanks for your response @Wrikken Useful Info! tnx a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"When creating a foreign key constraint, MySQL requires a usable index on both the referencing table and also on the referenced table. The index on the referencing table is created automatically if one doesn't exist, but the one on the referenced table needs to be created manually (Source). Yours appears to be missing."

See [MySQL Foreign Key Error 1005 errno 150](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063141/mysql-foreign-key-error-1005-errno-150)