# How to get around 'ON DELETE SET DEFAULT' not being accepted?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, innodb

I'll try to explain my situation.

I have an 'Employee' table. I have a 'Department' table with a 'DepHead' column which references an 'EmployeeID'.

I want to be able to delete Employees **without deleting** any departments of which they're the head. I can't use `ON DELETE SET NULL` because the 'DepHead' column is set to `NOT NULL` and is required to be so. It has a default value of '1' so i'd like, if possible, the 'DepHead' value to be changed to '1' if the referenced employeeID is deleted.

Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: What about creating a trigger on deletion which sets the value 1?

Comment: @AakashVerma Sounds like a good idea which I'd be willing to try. I'm not hugely familiar with triggers though. If yourself or someone could post a brief example that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Okay. I have got a good excerpt somewhere on it. Till then, what about altering the column to include a default value 1? That's much easier.

Comment: http://www.digitalpropulsion.org/Programming/Triggers_in_MySQL_5_0 See if this works for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [InnoDB mySQL unable to set "ON DELETE SET DEFAULT'. How to set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943459/innodb-mysql-unable-to-set-on-delete-set-default-how-to-set)

Comment: @AakashVerma Just having a default value on the column would solve the problem? If it would just set it to the default value if the relating employee was deleted then yes that's all I need it to do :)

Comment: @Heavenly Do you want the other columns of Department to retain data?

Comment: @AakashVerma Unfortunatley it didn't work as expected. I added a new department with a DepHead value of 6 relating to employee 6. When I deleted employee 6, the DepHead value remained as '6' rather than changing to it's default value of 1

Comment: @Heavenly Did you try what I have done in ny answer?

Comment: @AakashVerma I already have the constraints in place and the default value set, but I can't use 'ON DELETE SET DEFAULT' as you've used in the answer

Comment: @Heavenly I read your previous two comments and figured that you might have not done a `ON DELETE CASCADE` on the primary key in the Employee table. You might wanna do that when you want all the other columns to get deleted and DepHead to set to 1. If you don't want other columns to lose their data and only want DepHead to set to default, create a trigger on the deletion happening in Employee table.

Comment: In my opinion, `FOREIGN KEYS` have so many limitations and hiccups that they are rarely worth using.  Note how many of the Comments and Answers here are providing kludges for what might be simpler to do manually.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following, *in the order*:

Set a named constraint so that the DBMS doesn't set a random one which would be difficult to track:

```
ALTER TABLE Department ADD CONSTRAINT CON_DEP_HEAD DEFAULT N'1' FOR DepHead;
```

Now, as the Department table is referencing the Employee table, add a foreign key constraint

```
ALTER TABLE Department ADD CONSTRAINT CON_DEP_DEPHEADFK FOREIGN KEY DepHead REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID) ON DELETE SET DEFAULT;
```

Now, on deletion of a record in `Employee`, the corresponding children rows in `Department` would have their foreign key changed to *default*.

Read more about it [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete_null.php)

Comment: This information applies to SQL Server, not MySQL :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Maybe syntax wise, all I am pointing out to is the semantics.