# Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

these are my models :

Department Model:

```
    id  name                       tag                     created_at           updated_at  
------  -------------------------  -------------  -------------------  ---------------------
     1  عمومی                      public                      (NULL)                 (NULL)
```

user model :

```
id  username    password       is-admin      department_id
```

I wrote this code in my user migration:

```
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('department_id')->default(1);
    $table->foreign('department_id')->references('id')
    ->on('departments')->onDelete('SET DEFAULT')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

now, when i delete some records in the department table, I don't like to delete any user who has this department ID, I want to change depart_id in my user table to the default value (1), but when Delete the department that has relation with the user An error occurs!

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (fad.users, CONSTRAINT users_department_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (department_id) REFERENCES departments (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Comment: Shouldn't default be null? Since if you delete 1, the foreign key has no valid value it can be.

Comment: If you're using MySQL and InnoDB [you (apparently) can't use `SET DEFAULT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943459/innodb-mysql-unable-to-set-on-delete-set-default-how-to-set)

Comment: @mrhn you can set the default to be some sort of a default entity e.g. in this case maybe you have a department called "no department" which has all users that don't belong to any department so when you delete a department all users of that department get associated with the "no department" department. Not sure if this is what's happening here, just noting there's a "valid" use case for this

Comment: in his example he only has one department :/

Comment: @mrhn it seems like OP has abandoned the question so we may never know why they're using `SET DEFAULT` instead of `SET NULL`