# can not create table in mysql : Error code:1005(errno:150)

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, primary-key, mysql-workbench

I have two tables called `"purchase_order"` and `"purchase_order_details"`. The problem is when I try to create a `"purchase_order_details"` it gives me the following error

> Error Code: 1005. Can't create table
>   'motor_parts.purchase_order_details' (errno: 150) 0.125 sec

I'm using mysql workbench as GUI for creating tables I tried both writing script by hand and GUI based table implementation but both gave me the same error.

Here is the script for creating tables

```
create table purchase_order
(
date date,
sid     varchar(50),
bill_no varchar(10),
total   double(10,2),
uid     varchar(20),

primary key(date,sid,bill_no)

);

create table purchase_order_details
(
pdate       date,
sid         varchar(50),
bill_no     varchar(10),
pid         varchar(20),
quantity    double(10,5),
type        varchar(10),
price       double(10,2),
total       double(10,2),

primary key(pdate,sid,bill_no,pid),
constraint fk_pur_ord_det_date  foreign key(pdate) references purchase_order(date),
constraint fk_pur_ord_det_bill_no   foreign key(bill_no) references purchase_order(bill_no),
constraint fk_pur_ord_det_pid   foreign key(pid) references product(pid),
constraint fk_pur_ord_det_sid   foreign key(sid) references supplier(sid)
);
```

I have googled and searched Stack Overflow site and I couldn't find an answer .

I guess there is a problem with foreign key `"fk_pur_ord_det_bill_no"` in `"purchase_order_details"`.without `"fk_pur_ord_det_bill_no"` script executes perfectly fine.

I can't figure out what is the problem with that key.please help me.

thank you all.

Comment: field `sid` dont exist on your `purchase_order_details` table. So you cant create a constraint on that field.

Comment: field "sid" exist in my "purchase_order_details" . it is after the "pdate" value.

Comment: I finally found a answer.. credit goes to this question and answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063141/mysql-foreign-key-error-1005-errno-150

I created a index on "purchase_order" and created a table with all the foreign keys in "purchase_order_details".