# #1005 - Can't create table errno: 150

Tags: mysql

I have seen a lot of questions in Stackoerflow before asking this question

When I execute the below mlm_commission create table query,

I am getting the following error.

> 1005 - Can't create table 'mlm_new.mlm_commission' (errno: 150) (Details…)

Also When I click Details, I got the following text

> Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys

Create Commission Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mlm_commission
                (`weekno` int(11) NOT NULL,
                `level` int(11) NOT NULL,
                `username` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
                `PositionA` int(11) NOT NULL,
                `CFPositionA` int(11) NOT NULL,
                `PositionB` int(11) NOT NULL,
                `CFPositionB` int(11) NOT NULL,
                `PositionC` int(11) NOT NULL,
                `CFPositionC` int(11) NOT NULL,
                `ABLeft` int(11) NOT NULL,
                `CFABLeft` int(11) NOT NULL,
                `ABRight` int(11) NOT NULL,
                `CFABRight` int(11) NOT NULL,
                `CLeft` int(11) NOT NULL,
                `CFCLeft` int(11) NOT NULL,
                `CRight` int(11) NOT NULL,
                `CFCRight` int(11) NOT NULL,
                `ABMatchingPair` int(11) NOT NULL,
                `CMatchingPair` int(11) NOT NULL,
                `IsIncludedToParent` enum('Y','N'),
                `side` enum('L','R') NOT NULL,
                `leg` enum('0','1','2') NOT NULL,
                `parent_key` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
                `commission` int(11) NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(`username`) REFERENCES mlm_rtmfx_users(`username`),
                FOREIGN KEY(`side`) REFERENCES mlm_rtmfx_users(`side`),
                FOREIGN KEY(`leg`) REFERENCES mlm_rtmfx_users(`leg`),
                FOREIGN KEY(`parent_key`) REFERENCES mlm_rtmfx_users(`parent_key`),
                PRIMARY KEY(`username`,`weekno`,`level`));
```

I am referencing 4 foreign key values in mlm_rtmfx_commission table from the below table.

```
CREATE TABLE `mlm_rtmfx_users` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `user_id` varchar(1023) NOT NULL,
   `username` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
   `user_key` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
   `parent_key` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
   `sponsor_key` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
   `leg` enum('0','1','2') NOT NULL,
   `payment_status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
   `pinno` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `user_password` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
   `side` enum('L','R') NOT NULL,
   `iseligible` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL,
   `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   )
```

You can check that each foreign key references are having same name and type.

I have seen this [Error No:150](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063141/mysql-foreign-key-error-1005-errno-150) and I am confusing about indexes.

I also having the list of indexes in mlm_rtmfx_users table. Please check below.

[image: mlm_rtmfx_users index]

I got the index table from the following query.

```
SHOW INDEX FROM mlm_rtmfx_users
```

Please clarify me where do I go wrong? If my question is not clear, Please let me know.

Comment: Does `username` need to have a length of 500? MySQL will refuse to index a VARCHAR column that large.

Comment: please update your CREATE TABLE statement with the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE mlm_rtmfx_users`. Even in your screenshot I can't see any key on `side`, `leg` and `parent_key`. All those are you referencing.

Comment: _Prefix support and lengths of prefixes (where supported) are storage engine dependent. For example, a prefix can be up to 1000 bytes long for MyISAM tables, and 767 bytes for InnoDB tables._ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: What is mainly missing are _individual_ indices on the non-PK columns in the referenced table.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski `username` max length can be reduced to 50.

Comment: @Guna Do you have [innodb_large_prefix](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_large_prefix) enabled?

Comment: @VMai In the `mlm_rtmfx_users` table, I don't have index key for `side`, `leg`,and `parent_key`

Comment: @Guna But you reference them, i.e. `FOREIGN KEY( side) REFERENCES mlm_rtmfx_users( side ),` Have a look at your own statement please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two requirements to `FOREIGN KEY` creation. First, the referencing columns must have exactly the same data types as the referenced columns. Second, the referenced columns must be indexed exactly as the referencing columns are. That is, if you have 3 single `FOREIGN KEY`s, you need 3 corresponding indices on the referenced table. If you had one compound `FOREIGN KEY` comprising 3 columns, you would need a corresponding compound index on the same 3 columns in the referenced table.

You have *some* of the columns referenced in `mlm_rtmfx_users` indexed, but *each* of the referenced columns must have an index matching that of the `FOREIGN KEY` columns in the referencing table. So you will need to add indices on `side,leg,parent_key,user`.

If you reduce the length of `username`, you will not exceed the InnoDB limit of 767 bytes per index.

```
CREATE TABLE `mlm_rtmfx_users` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `user_id` varchar(1023) NOT NULL,
   `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `user_key` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
   `parent_key` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
   `sponsor_key` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
   `leg` enum('0','1','2') NOT NULL,
   `payment_status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
   `pinno` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `user_password` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
   `side` enum('L','R') NOT NULL,
   `iseligible` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL,
   `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    -- More indices are needed in the parent table:
    INDEX (`username`),
    INDEX (`side`),
    INDEX (`leg`),
    INDEX (`parent_key`)
 )
```

If you must keep `username` with a long length of 500, you will need to [enable `innodb_long_prefix`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_large_prefix) to increase the permitted byte length of the index.

With the additional indices added to the parent table (and the `username` length reduced into InnoDB's index limit), the tables can successfully be created. [Here it is in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49501)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I learnt that if an attribute is referenced, It must be indexed in the parent table. Am I right?

Comment: That is right. I just added a paragraph to the top explaining that better.