# mysql Error 150: foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

Hello every one I'm stuck on one problem please help me to solve it

**I have reffered same question but have not found the proper solution**

I have one table `pay_test_table`, I want to add foreign key reference of this table to other table `pay_test1_table`.

I have not created any reference in `pay_test_table` so I dropped that table and recreated it but my problem is I always get error:

```
Can't create table  error150
ID as a primary key in pay_test_table
ID as foreignkey in pay_test1_table
```

Comment: There are other questions on SO that reference same issue, have you researched those? For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063141/mysql-foreign-key-error-1005-errno-150

Comment: yes i referred that but it does not give solution to me

Comment: @Dan i have referred that question but i have not found solution wat to do with my table so that i will not get that error

Comment: Have you dropped index for the table & then tried?