# Can't create table OrderLine errno 150 Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hei, im trying to add new table Order line

> CREATE TABLE Ordrelinje (
>       OrdreNr INTEGER NOT NULL,
>       PNr CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
>       PrisPrEnhet DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
>       Antall INTEGER NOT NULL,
>       PRIMARY KEY ( OrdreNr, PNr ),
>       INDEX (OrdreNr),
>       INDEX (PNr),
>       FOREIGN KEY ( OrdreNr ) REFERENCES Ordre(OrdreNr),
>       FOREIGN KEY ( PNr ) REFERENCES Produkt(PNr) ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

phpmyadming gives me message

> ' #1005 - Can't create table 'pizza.ordrelinje' (errno: 150) '

I think its something wrong with primary, foreign keys of other tables but im not pretty sure.
How should i solve this problem?

Comment: Show schema for `ordre` and `Produkt` table.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061293/mysql-cant-create-table-errno-150 it seems to be the same error.

Comment: ORDRETABLE
OrdreNr
Dato
Antall
Pris
PNr
Epost

PRODUKTTABLE
PNr
PNavn
Pris

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Foreign Key Error 1005 errno 150](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063141/mysql-foreign-key-error-1005-errno-150)

Comment: SOLVED IT! it was incompatible types thanks!