# How do I declare foreign keys referencing multi-value primary key in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I keep getting the error "#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint" when I try to declare more than one foreign key for a table. I know it is possible to declare more than one foreign key in a table so I am unsure as to why I am receiving the error. I'm pretty sure my error has to do with referencing multi-valued primary keys but I am unsure how to go about fixing it. All help is much appreciated and thank you in advance!

edit: The first 4 tables work correctly. The last 4 are the ones I am having trouble with.

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Course (
CourseNo INT NOT NULL, 
CourseName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
Department VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY(CourseNo)
);

CREATE TABLE Student (
SSN INT NOT NULL, 
FirstName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
LastName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
Street VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
City VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
State VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
Zip MEDIUMINT NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY(SSN)
);

CREATE TABLE ClassRoom (
RoomNo INT NOT NULL, 
Building VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
Capacity INT NOT NULL, 
/* CONSTRAINT pk_ClassID */ PRIMARY KEY(RoomNo, Building)
);

CREATE TABLE Section (
CourseNumber INT NOT NULL, 
SectionNo INT NOT NULL, 
Instructor VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
/*CONSTRAINT pk_SectionID*/ PRIMARY KEY(CourseNumber, SectionNo), 
FOREIGN KEY (CourseNumber) REFERENCES Course(CourseNo)
);

CREATE TABLE Enrolls (
StuSSN INT NOT NULL, 
SecNo INT NOT NULL, 
CNo INT NOT NULL, 
/* CONSTRAINT pk_EnrollID */ PRIMARY KEY(StuSSN, SecNo, CNo), 
FOREIGN KEY (StuSSN) REFERENCES Student(SSN), 
FOREIGN KEY (SecNo) REFERENCES Section(SectionNo), 
FOREIGN KEY (CNo) REFERENCES Course(CourseNo)
);

CREATE TABLE Exam (
CNum INT NOT NULL, 
SectionNum INT NOT NULL, 
ExamNo INT NOT NULL, 
E_Date DATE NOT NULL, 
E_Time TIME NOT NULL, 
/* CONSTRAINT pk_ExamID */ PRIMARY KEY(CNum, SectionNum, ExamNo), 
FOREIGN KEY (CNum) REFERENCES Course(CourseNo), 
FOREIGN KEY (SectionNum) REFERENCES Section(SectionNo)
);

CREATE TABLE Takes (
StudentSSN INT NOT NULL, 
CourseNum INT NOT NULL, 
SecNum INT NOT NULL, 
ExamNum INT NOT NULL, 
Result TINYINT NOT NULL, 
/* CONSTRAINT pk_TakesID */ PRIMARY KEY(StudentSSN, CourseNum, SecNum, ExamNum), 
FOREIGN KEY (StudentSSN) REFERENCES Student(SSN), 
FOREIGN KEY (CourseNum) REFERENCES Course(CourseNo), 
FOREIGN KEY (SecNum) REFERENCES Section(SectionNo), 
FOREGIN KEY (ExamNum) REFERENCES Exam(ExamNo)
);

CREATE TABLE ConductedIn (
RoomNum INT NOT NULL, 
Build VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
CNumber INT NOT NULL, 
SectionNumber INT NOT NULL, 
ExamNumber INT NOT NULL, 
/* CONSTRAINT pk_ConductedID */ PRIMARY KEY(RoomNum, Build, CNumber, SectionNumber, ExamNumber), 
FOREIGN KEY (RoomNum) REFERENCES ClassRoom(RoomNo), 
FOREIGN KEY (Build) REFERENCES ClassRoom(Building), 
FOREIGN KEY (CNumber) REFERENCES Course(CourseNo), 
FOREIGN KEY (SectionNumber) REFERENCES Section(SectionNo), 
FOREIGN KEY(ExamNumber) REFERENCES Exam(ExamNo)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll refer you here for more details: [MySQL Foreign Key Error 1005 errno 150](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063141/mysql-foreign-key-error-1005-errno-150)

essentially your problem is that in your `Section` table, you have a composite primary key `PRIMARY KEY(CourseNumber, SectionNo)`, in your `Enrolls` table you then try to refer to a field `SectionNo` of table `Section`, but there is no index on that field. Any referenced field must have an index.

So, make sure that any field you reference as a foreign key has an index on its own (e.g. `PRIMARY(fieldname)` `UNIQUE(fieldname)` `INDEX(fieldname)`)

Comment: So basically all i need to do is add an index property to every field i reference with a foreign key?