# PHP MyAdmin Altering an existing table to create foreign keys

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

first post so very sorry if this seems like an obvious answer. Here's the premise of my problem. I have a database I am managing using PhpMyAdmin. I have a table called "Schedules" and want the id of the drivers on the schedule to be a foreign key that references a larger table "Users" where the ID column in this table is a primary key. Here is what i tried:

```
     ALTER TABLE `Schedules` 
       ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_DriverID` 
   FOREIGN KEY (`Driver_ID`) 
REFERENCES `users`(`ID`);
```

However, i get this error:

> 1005 - Can't create table 'Scheduler.#sql-3b7_3b9d' (errno: 150)
>   (Details…)

I am really at a loss with this error because im not trying to create any tables just alter an existing one. Thanks again and sorry if I butchered the formatting.

Comment: I'm not sure where that table name comes from or if it's purely internal to the engine, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063141/mysql-foreign-key-error-1005-errno-150 may be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mainly is due to a wrong primary key reference in your table.

Usually this means the key you are referencing does not exist / there might be difference in datatype between the FOREIGN KEY and the REFERENCED column / or there might be difference in column name.

Make sure that

1. you have a column named `ID` in users table
2. `Driver_ID` column have the same data type as `ID` column in Users table. Make sure both are exactly of the same data type.

Refer [this](http://verysimple.com/2006/10/22/mysql-error-number-1005-cant-create-table-mydbsql-328_45frm-errno-150/) for more information