# MySQL phpMyAdmin: Error 150 (#1005)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am really not sure what the problem is, but I keep getting an error on the `Works_On` table that I am trying to create.

```
CREATE TABLE Works_On(tid INT NOT NULL, startingDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, id INT, Primary Key(id), Foreign Key(tid) REFERENCES Team(tid),Foreign Key(id) REFERENCES Cases(id));

CREATE TABLE Cases(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, priority INT, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, description TEXT, completionDate datetime, status VARCHAR(20), cid INT, Foreign Key(cid) REFERENCES Contact(cid), Primary Key(id));

    CREATE TABLE Gives_Problem_To(tid INT NOT NULL, onDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, cid INT NOT NULL, Primary Key(tid), Foreign Key(tid) REFERENCES Team(tid),Foreign Key(cid) REFERENCES Contact(cid));
```

The error I get is: #1005 - Can't create table

I tried to find out what this error is and I get this:

```
Storage Engines
InnoDB Documentation

Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys
```

So this makes me think it has an issue with my Foreign Key, but I cannot tell what the problem really is with it.

**EDIT:** I tried to move the CREATE TABLE statement for Cases to the top in-case the foreign key issue is arising due to Cases table not being made before it is referenced to and now my phpAdmin is stuck on loading...

Comment: You have to create the table `Team` first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Foreign Key Error 1005 errno 150](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063141/mysql-foreign-key-error-1005-errno-150)

Comment: Team table already exists. I think that the Cases table's create table statement should be at the top. I am trying to verfiy this is true but myPhpAdmin is frozen, so I cannot verify that the error goes away after I paste the Create Table Case statement to the top.

Answer (score 0):

Moving Create Table statement of Cases to top fixed the problem. Anytime you are creating a Foreign Key constraint on a table, that table has to exist before you are able to reference it. Solution looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Cases(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, priority INT, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, description TEXT, completionDate datetime, status VARCHAR(20), cid INT, Foreign Key(cid) REFERENCES Contact(cid), Primary Key(id));

CREATE TABLE Gives_Problem_To(tid INT NOT NULL, onDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, cid INT NOT NULL, Primary Key(tid), Foreign Key(tid) REFERENCES Team(tid),Foreign Key(cid) REFERENCES Contact(cid));

CREATE TABLE Works_On(tid INT NOT NULL, startingDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, id INT, Primary Key(id), Foreign Key(tid) REFERENCES Team(tid),Foreign Key(id) REFERENCES Cases(id));
```