# ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'tracker_phonetracker.location_share' (errno: -1)

Tags: mysql

I am facing this problem in this query .

```
CREATE TABLE location_share ( 
    circle_id INT ,
    user_id INT , 
    location_sharing_id  INT , 
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id ,circle_id  ) , 
    CONSTRAINT fkcircle1 FOREIGN KEY (circle_id) REFERENCES circle(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE , 
    CONSTRAINT fkuser1 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE , 
    CONSTRAINT fksharing_policy FOREIGN KEY (location_sharing_id) REFERENCES share(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE 
) ENGINE = INNODB
```

Mysql shows me error 1005 :

> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table
>   'tracker_phonetracker.location_share' (errno: -1)

Other tables on which this query is dependent are :

Table : circle

```
CREATE TABLE circle (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , 
    name varchar(35)
) ENGINE=INNODB
```

Table  : user

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , 
    contact_no VARCHAR(25) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
    email VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE  NOT     NULL, 
    first_name  VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL , 
    last_name VARCHAR(25) , 
    device_id VARCHAR(250)NOT NULL  , 
    image_path VARCHAR(180) , 
    password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL , 
    latitude VARCHAR(18) , 
    longitude VARCHAR(18) 
) ENGINE=INNODB
```

Table : share

```
CREATE TABLE share (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , 
    policy VARCHAR(6) UNIQUE NOT NULL 
)
```

Can anybody plz tell me what's wrong with my query .

Thanks !!

Comment: There might be something useful in this question for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063141/mysql-foreign-key-error-1005-errno-150

Answer (score 0):

From the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html

> 1005 (ER_CANT_CREATE_TABLE)
>
> Cannot create table. If the error message refers to error 150, table
>   creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly
>   formed. If the error message refers to error −1, table creation
>   probably failed because the table includes a column name that matched
>   the name of an internal InnoDB table.

This is caused by using `user` you can fix this by escaping references to `user`:

```
 REFERENCES `user`(id)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer . You mean to say should i remove statement referencing user table . I think i did not get you .

Comment: @DeepakRathore No need to remove, Just escape the `user` by adding `\`` around it.

Comment: i tried using escaping character , but it still shows me same error 1005

Comment: @DeepakRathore What version of MySQL are you running on? The above works for me? Have you created your other tables first?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `location_share` (
  `circle_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `location_sharing_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`circle_id`),
  KEY `fkcircle1` (`circle_id`),
  KEY `fksharing_policy` (`location_sharing_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fkcircle1` FOREIGN KEY (`circle_id`) REFERENCES `circle` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fksharing_policy` FOREIGN KEY (`location_sharing_id`) REFERENCES `share` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fkuser1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: There is not wrong in it. Please run the query which I give and let me know it works' I have replicated ur tables structure in my DB and it worked

Comment: hi i tried your query but it giving me now         error #1005  can't create table

Comment: check this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html  i didn't face issue in creating ur table in my DB.... is ur reference tables exists?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION** (works for me):

1. Rename the table in the script. Ex: wp_users to wp_users1
2. Run the script. No error.
3. Rename the table with Operation in MySQL (or your Database Engine).
4. Ready.

Regards!