# mysql. can't create schema when using composite UNIQUE key. ERROR 1005 (HY000): (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to create a simple schema, see below. But for some reason I get this weird 150 error.I was able to narrow the problem down to Unique key declaration: `UNIQUE KEY (fk_im_savegroups_sgcode, sscode)`. If I refactor declaration to this: `UNIQUE KEY (sscode)` - it works.

Could someone explain to me why can't I use a composite index?

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test447;
CREATE DATABASE test447 CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
USE test447;


CREATE TABLE im_savegroups (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    sgcode VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY (sgcode)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE im_savespecs (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fk_im_savegroups_sgcode VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    sscode VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    max_w INT UNSIGNED,
    max_h INT UNSIGNED,
    ratio_x INT UNSIGNED,
    ratio_y INT UNSIGNED,
    quality INT UNSIGNED,
    format VARCHAR(10),
    rel_dir VARCHAR(400),
    is_retina TINYINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
    is_preferred TINYINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_im_savegroups_sgcode) REFERENCES im_savegroups (sgcode) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE KEY (fk_im_savegroups_sgcode, sscode)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE im_originals (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fk_im_savespecs_sscode VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    alt VARCHAR(180),
    filename VARCHAR(64),
    caption VARCHAR(1024),
    credit VARCHAR(1024),
    expires_at DATETIME,
    created_at DATETIME,
    updated_at DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_im_savespecs_sscode) REFERENCES im_savespecs (sscode) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: on which table ur getting this error? im getting an error while creating im_originals

Comment: Can you try by giving quotes like `UNIQUE KEY 'my_uk' ('fk_im_savegroups_sgcode', 'sscode')`

Comment: last table. first two tables get created just fine.

Comment: quoting aint the issue

Comment: @Crazy2crack yeah. I've tried with quotes - no difference.

Comment: Go through this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4063172/4295763) Might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Parent must have unique key on that column

```
CREATE TABLE im_savegroups (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    sgcode VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY (sgcode)
) ENGINE=InnoDB; -- CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE im_savespecs (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fk_im_savegroups_sgcode VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    sscode VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    max_w INT UNSIGNED,
    max_h INT UNSIGNED,
    ratio_x INT UNSIGNED,
    ratio_y INT UNSIGNED,
    quality INT UNSIGNED,
    format VARCHAR(10),
    rel_dir VARCHAR(400),
    is_retina TINYINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
    is_preferred TINYINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_im_savegroups_sgcode) REFERENCES im_savegroups (sgcode) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE KEY (fk_im_savegroups_sgcode, sscode),
    unique key (sscode) -- ******************************
) ENGINE=innodb CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE im_originals (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fk_im_savespecs_sscode VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    alt VARCHAR(180),
    filename VARCHAR(64),
    caption VARCHAR(1024),
    credit VARCHAR(1024),
    expires_at DATETIME,
    created_at DATETIME,
    updated_at DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_orig_ss FOREIGN KEY (`fk_im_savespecs_sscode`) REFERENCES im_savespecs(sscode) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

) ENGINE=innodb CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

### Edit:

my biggest problems with any of this:

1) is that of the column is a varchar(20) and the composite is on two of them, and the OP might want a second composite. Those are quite wide composites in my book.

2) the FK's should be back to **unique** slim codes in a code table (not shown or even in existence), or to pk's that are ints. That speaks to index optimization.

I would even make the bold statement that FK's ought to nearly always go back to ints, unless it is such unbearable mental contemplation and the `code` itself is slim like a zipcode.

Comment: But he doesn't want sscode as unique key needs a composite one.. may be i m not sure

Comment: @DrewPierce ahh you're right. I see what happens. can I have a foreign key to two columns combo?

Comment: Ok... Thanks. @DrewPierce

Comment: concerning the table **im_savespecs**, if you have a **UNIQUE** composite index going the other way (say in addition to the composite you have or without the other composite you have) ... and sscode is **left-most**, it **DOES** work without the unique index on just (sscode). I just tested that

Comment: @DrewPierce I guess I can't picture what you mean by "going the other way" - could u post an example?

Comment: ok i will do an edit at bottom of answer give me a few minutes

Comment: Notice that MySQL has no requirement on it being unique. The field in the parent table can have a primary, unique, or plain non-constrained index.

Comment: true. but as it is a code, i would be going after a code table that has it unique, otherwise I would probably have a pretty screwed up code table now wouldn't i

Comment: which does bring up the question of why is this FK going to a non code table but rather a **random child table** if you will

Comment: so I guess til that is sorted out, i should just say 'going the other way' means **flipped**  .... so a composite on (x1,x2) would be a composite on (x2,x1) ... in addition to or replacing, depending on the OP discretion

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of
>   columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index
>   where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the
>   same order.

Emphasis on "first columns".

So just switch the order of the fields in the unique key:

```
UNIQUE KEY (sscode, fk_im_savegroups_sgcode),
```