# MySQL cannot create table error code 1005

Tags: mysql, database

When I try to execute this statement I got this error:

> #1005 - Can't create table 'school2.#sql-1060_74' (errno: 150)
>
> #Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys

I can't figure out what is wrong.

```
CREATE TABLE `class` (
`class_num` varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
`sec` varchar(10) NOT NULL ,
`tmpo_no` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`class_num`,`sec`));

CREATE TABLE `class_has_taken` (
`class_num` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`sec` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`std_id` INT NOT NULL,
`year` DATE NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE `class_has_taken` ADD CONSTRAINT `class_has_taken_fk0` FOREIGN KEY (`class_num`) REFERENCES `class`(`class_num`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `class_has_taken` ADD CONSTRAINT `class_has_taken_fk2` FOREIGN KEY (`sec`) REFERENCES `class`(`sec`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: There must be an other statement for creating table school2 where you get these error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Foreign Key Error 1005 errno 150](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063141/mysql-foreign-key-error-1005-errno-150)

Comment: school2 is my database name. i am actually executing it on phpmyadmin.

Comment: Read the [manual section on foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), particularly the section on the requirements for indexes. You're missing an index on your parent table.

Comment: @user2825707 Please add the Engine InnoDB while creating table and try. Also remove On Delete.

Comment: i have added innoDB but still not working

Answer (score 0):

1. Please add the Engine InnoDB while creating table and try.
2. Also remove On Delete from your alter query. Because you are trying to set null. But you mentioned some of your fields are not null in create table.
3. If you see still error, then run this,

   SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

It will say why your constrains are failing.