# Django: Foreign key to User error

Tags: mysql, django

I'm having this lines in every table in my db. I'm using django 1.8.

```
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

I also tried the code below and I get the same error.

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

This is what I see in terminal using `syncdb`.

`cy_thal` is the name of my db.

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py:24: Remo
vedInDjango19Warning: The syncdb command will be removed in Django 1.9
  warnings.warn("The syncdb command will be removed in Django 1.9", RemovedInDja
ngo19Warning)

Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: chartit, pagination, staticfiles, autocomplete_li
ght, messages, bootstrap3_datetime, eReg, crispy_forms, bootstrap3
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Creating table eReg_demographic
    Creating table eReg_icd_10
    Creating table eReg_pregnancy
    Creating table eReg_diagnosis
    Creating table eReg_clinical_data
    Creating table eReg_clinical_data_two
    Creating table eReg_a_b_sickle_thal
    Creating table eReg_redcell_enzyme_dis
    Creating table eReg_redcell_membrane_dis
    Creating table eReg_cong_dyseryth_anaemia
    Creating table eReg_ext_centers
    Running deferred SQL...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390,
 in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 441,
 in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py"
, line 25, in handle
    call_command("migrate", **options)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
120, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 441,
 in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py
", line 179, in handle
    created_models = self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py
", line 317, in sync_apps
    cursor.execute(statement)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in
execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in
execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 62, in
execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 12
4, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defau
lterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1005, "Can't create table 'cy_thal.#sql-f8c_9
' (errno: 150)")
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should use the code given in the error to search more details about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063141/mysql-foreign-key-error-1005-errno-150 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018584/error-code-1005-cant-create-table-errno-150. MySQL needs indexes to set the FK constraint, one of the two may not have been automatically created.

Comment: @Pawamoy And how can I do this from models.py in django?

Comment: Did you try to run `./manage.py migrate auth` before `./manage.py migrate` ? In some cases `auth` app must be migrated before the others.

Comment: @Pawamoy This is the solution! Please add it as an answer to accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases the `auth` app must be migrated before the other apps, because it generates all the permissions, and also the indexes of very often used models like `User`, which are required for setting foreign key constraints in other models.

Run `./manage.py migrate auth`, then you should be able to do a standard `./manage.py migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure which is the error, but I'd try the next.

After making changes to models execute these lines:
    `python manage.py makemigrations appname`
    `python manage.py migrate appname`

If error remains, try:
    `python manage.py syncdb`

EDIT: I edited my answer as Daniel Roseman suggested. Django 1.8 supports Migrations. No need to use South.

Comment: `schemamigration` is not supported.

Comment: ok, you should install south to use my solution. South is a Django app that is used to modify the database structure when you modify models. Really useful.

Comment: to install south: 1.pip install south, 2. add it to INSTALLED_APPS, 3. manage.py syncdb.

Comment: This is a bad answer. Django 1.8 has migrations built in, there is no need to install South.