# Unable to add foreign key in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

In a laravel migration file I have the following code:

```
   Schema::table('stripe_customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
   });
```

'user_id' is an existing unsigned integer column in the table 'stripe_customers'.

'id' is a primary key column in 'users'.

However when I run the migrate command I get the following error message:

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                      
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'thedealerapp.#sql-47a_78859' (errno: 150) (SQL:  
   alter table `stripe_customers` add constraint stripe_customers_user_id_foreign foreign key (`user_id`)   
  references `users` (`id`))                                                                                

  [PDOException]                                                                                      
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'thedealerapp.#sql-47a_78859' (errno: 150)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: What happens if you remove that call and try adding it to the DB directly?

Comment: Usually err 150 is happening because of a mismatch between the column types or table collation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Foreign Key Error 1005 errno 150](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063141/mysql-foreign-key-error-1005-errno-150)

Comment: All the values on the `user_id` are valid user ids? Both columns (`stripe_customers.user_id` and `users.id` have the same data type?

Comment: `'id' is a primary key column in 'users'` - is `id` also unsigned integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there's a few different possible causes for failure to create a foreign key.

- Is `users`.`id` indexed? MySQL requires an index on both tables to create a foreign key. While `stripe_customers`.`user_id` is created implicitly, make sure `users`.`id`.
- Do you have content in `stripe_customers` which could fail the foreign key check? That would cause an error on creating the foreign key.
- Have you confirmed that the column type of both tables is the same? MySQL will require that both are the same
- Can you confirm that both tables are in the same schema? If one of your tables is somehow in a different DB, then MySQL wants an explicit reference to the DB.

Comment: The issue was one column was unsigned, while another was not. Thanks for the help